# Can ever x Will ever

Tags: meaning, grammar

Is there any difference between the meaning of the following sentences:

"The world has much more to offer than you **can** ever imagine."

"The world has much more to offer than you **will** ever imagine."

Or are they equivalents?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Coud you explain in detail what "Can ever x Will ever" is supposed to mean? Are you hoping your "x" will be taken for "v" meaning "versus" or something else, please?

Comment: I don't think "will ever imagine" is a common phrase. "can ever imagine" is.

Answer (score 1):

"can ever" refers to the ability to dp something. So the first sentence means that it's not possible to imagine how much the world has to offer.

"will ever" is a predication about whether something will happen. So the second sentence means that you'll never imagine how much the world has to offer.

The two meanings are related, though: if you can't do something, then you obviously won't do it (although you might try). The two sentences emphasize different aspects of this relationship.

The first form is much more common:

[image]